# Best way to extract rows with none-matching column values for two python pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, filter

I would like to know the best approach for the following pandas `dataframe` comparison task:

1. Two dataframes `df_a` and `df_b` with both having columns = `['W','X','Y','Z']`:

```
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 2, 2, 3],
    ['b', 5, 3, 5],
    ['b', 7, 6, 44],
    ['c', 3, 12, 19],
    ['c', 7, 13, 45],
    ['c', 3, 13, 45],
    ['d', 5, 11, 90],
    ['d', 9, 33, 44]
                    ], columns=['W','X','Y','Z'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 2, 2, 3],
    ['a', 4, 3, 15],
    ['b', 5, 12, 24],
    ['b', 7, 6, 44],
    ['c', 3, 12, 19],
    ['d', 3, 23, 45],
    ['d', 6, 11, 91],
    ['d', 9, 33, 44]
                    ], columns=['W','X','Y','Z'])
```

2. Extract those rows from `df_a` that do not have a match in columns `['W','X']` in `df_b`
3. Extract those rows from `df_b` that do not have a match in columns `['W','X']` in `df_a`

Since I am kind of newbie to pandas (and could not find any other source that gives information on  the mentioned task) help-out is very much appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way is using `left outer` merge with `indicator=True`  and select `left_only` using `query`

```
cols = ['W', 'X']

df_a_only = (df_a.merge(df_b[cols], on=cols, indicator=True, how='left')
                 .query('_merge=="left_only"')[df_a.columns])

Out[87]:
   W  X   Y   Z
4  c  7  13  45
6  d  5  11  90

df_b_only = (df_b.merge(df_a[cols], on=cols, indicator=True, how='left')
                 .query('_merge=="left_only"')[df_b.columns])

Out[89]:
   W  X   Y   Z
1  a  4   3  15
6  d  3  23  45
7  d  6  11  91
```

---

**Note**: if your dataframe is huge, itt is better doing one full `outer merge` than using 2 `left outer merge` as above and choosing `left_only` and `right_only` accordingly. However, in doing full `outer merge`, you need to do post process of `NaN`, converting float back to integer and rename columns.

Comment: Thnx alot, that solved it whereby I did not try out your second proposal for huge dataframes yet.